# Configuring a router for a web server

Tags: web-server, router

I have made a website, and it'll be in private beta in a couple of days. I want this private beta to run on my development machine first, so it's easy to make changes suggested using IRC.

The problem is that I have a router in my home (Thomson SpeedTouch 780). My development server runs on port 3000, connected to that router.

How can I make my dev-server available to others through this router? Do I need to do port forwarding or is it something else? Oh, and I have no firewall on my computer and it's an iMac. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your router should be in "Gateway" OR NAT mode.  You'll configure the port 3000 to go to your dev server on port 3000 in some sort of "port forwarding" menu.  Keep in mind that if your DEV server is on DHCP you'll need to put it on a static address.

The NAT/Port Forwarding needs to have a static address INSIDE to point to.